# dataTable issue in PDF page size and orientation

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatable, datatable-buttons

I have used datatable plugin for export pdf, csv, xls and print. I have problem in pdf view.

When I click on download pdf button my pdf file data not coming full width. Please check this link - https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/pdfPage.html

Screenshot:

[image]

code:

```
    {extend: 'copy'},
    {extend: 'csv'},
    {extend: 'excel', title: 'DownloadExcel'},
    {extend: 'pdf'},
    {extend: 'print',
        customize: function(win) {
            $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
            $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
            $(win.document.body).find('table')
                    .addClass('compact')
                    .css('font-size', 'inherit');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `{extend: 'pdf'}` to `{extend: 'pdfHtml5'}` and add `orientation:'landscape'`
and add to class `compact` `width:100%;`

Comment: Where I will add `compact` `width:100%`

Comment: You can add it in the css api .css('font-size': 'inherit','width' : '100%' );