# DataTables PDF horizontal export with CSV export button as well

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to change my PDF export to horizontal but the examples only include the PDF export button. While I have both CSV and PDF button so I'm wondering where will I place my CSV button.

Current Code:

```
$('#sales').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5'
                ],
                "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
            });
```

I want to apply this:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'LEGAL'
            }
        ]
    } );
```

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805342/datatable-issue-in-pdf-page-size-and-orientation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a snippet from a working solution (text is German, either delete or translate into your language).
It will add 4 Buttons: [image]

```
dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                titleAttr: 'Sichtbare Spalten auswählen (gilt auch für Export)',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                titleAttr: 'Tabelle als CSV exportieren',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
            },
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                titleAttr: 'Tabelle in Zwischenspeicher kopieren',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                title: 'Filialübersicht',
                titleAttr: 'Tabelle als Exceltabelle exportieren',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                title: 'Filialübersicht',
                titleAttr: 'Tabelle als PDF exportieren',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'help',
                titleAttr: 'Hilfe anzeigen',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="color:#FF480D;" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
            }
```

The last button (Help) is a custom one, opens a modal window with some help text.